# How to get a printer property value in render filter in Win7?

Tags: c++, printing, driver

I'm developing a v4 printer driver and I added a custom `PRINTER_PROPERTY` to my `gpd` file as follows:

```
*Feature: Pdl
{
    *Name: "Printer Definition Language"
    *FeatureType: PRINTER_PROPERTY
    *PrintSchemaKeywordMap: "Pdl"
    *DefaultOption: ps
    *Option: ps
    {
        *Name:  "Postscript"
    }
    *Option: pcl
    {
        *Name:  "PCL"
    }
}
```

I'm able to read its value in win 8 using `IPrinterPropertyBag` interface, but what should I do in win 7?

Piece of code which works in Win8:

```
VARIANT qPropBag;
if (SUCCEEDED(m_pIPropertyBag->GetProperty(XPS_FP_QUEUE_PROPERTY_BAG, &qPropBag)))
{
    auto pdisp = (IDispatch*)qPropBag.ppdispVal;
    IPrinterPropertyBag * pBag;
    if (SUCCEEDED(pdisp->QueryInterface<IPrinterPropertyBag>(&pBag)))
    {
        BSTR val;
        if (SUCCEEDED(pBag->GetString(L"Config:Pdl", &val))) {
            sFormat = val;
        }

        pBag->Release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it by myself (and a [help of MS guys](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/8b4a3263-0d24-466c-83c9-3fdc82e72d5a/how-to-get-a-printer-property-value-in-render-filter-in-win7?forum=wdk)) and here is the code:

```
VARIANT helper;
if (SUCCEEDED(m_pIPropertyBag->GetProperty(L"IPrintCoreHelper", &helper))) {

    IPrintCoreHelper * m_pCoreHelper;
    if (SUCCEEDED(V_UNKNOWN(&helper)->QueryInterface(IID_IPrintCoreHelper, reinterpret_cast<VOID**>(&m_pCoreHelper)))) {
        PCSTR val;
        if (SUCCEEDED(m_pCoreHelper->GetOption(NULL, 0, "Pdl", &val)))
            strcpy(sFormat, val); // usage

        m_pCoreHelper->Release();
    }
}
VariantClear(&helper);
```